# Role Based Access using groups in django and drf

Tags: django, authentication, django-rest-framework, permissions, user-permissions

I have 2 models named Menu-Items and Category.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField()
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255, db_index=True)

class MenuItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length= 255, db_index=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, db_index=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(to=Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

I have 3 types of users (Managers, Delivery Crew, and Customers).

**Manager**-> Can perform CRUD on Menu-items.

**Delivery Crew (DC)** -> can only view(get and list) menu-items.

**Customer** -> can only view category and menu-items

I have done authentication using Djoser. I have created 3 groups of users(managers, dc, and customers) and have added the necessary permissions to the groups.

[image]

[image]

Now how do I ensure that when a manager logs in he is able to perform the actions that he is allowed to and the same for Dc and customers?

Here's what I did.
I created 2 permissions isManager, and isDC.

```
class IsManager(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name= "Manager").exists()
class IsDeliveryCrew(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user.groups.filter(name= "Delivery Crew").exists()
```

and in my views

```
class MenuItemManagerView(ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MenuItem.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MenuItemSerilaizer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsManager]

class MenuItemDeliveryCrewView(ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView):
        queryset = MenuItem.objects.all()
        serializer_class = MenuItemSerilaizer
        permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsDeliveryCrew]
```

Now, it is doing the basic task of checking if the logged-in user is a manager, it allows the CRUD, and if the user is a DC, it allows list & retrieve; otherwise throws unauthorized....which is great.

But, this is how I knew it was not working the way it should.

I removed view access from the Manager group.
I logged in as a user named "manager", who belongs to group.....Manager.
[image]

[image]

I did a get-call (list), and it still works???? Why??

[image]
I need to know how to check the permissions associated with each group in django or drf?

My logic only checks if a user belongs to a group, but not the if that group to which the user belongs has permission to make the call. In this case, if user "manager"  who belongs to group Manager has permission to perform list/retrieve action.

PS: I tried to explain my problem, the best way I could. I am sorry if the question is stupid, I am quite new to DRF and django in general.